# XMLHttpRequest Event Listeners not Working on Edge

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, microsoft-edge

```
S3Upload.prototype.uploadToS3 = function(file, url, public_url, opts) {
      var this_s3upload, type, xhr;
      this_s3upload = this;
      type = opts && opts.type || file.type;
      xhr = this.createCORSRequest('PUT', url);
      if (!xhr) {
        this.onError('CORS not supported');
      } else {
        xhr.onload = function() {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            this_s3upload.onProgress(100, 'Upload completed.', public_url, file);
            return this_s3upload.onFinishS3Put(public_url, file);
          } else {
            return this_s3upload.onError('Upload error: ' + xhr.status, file);
          }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function() {
          return this_s3upload.onError('XHR error.', file);
        };
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
          var percentLoaded;
          if (e.lengthComputable) {
            percentLoaded = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
            return this_s3upload.onProgress(percentLoaded, (percentLoaded === 100 ? 'Finalizing.' : 'Uploading.'), public_url, file);
          }
        };
      }
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', type);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('x-amz-acl', 'public-read');
      return xhr.send(file);
    };
```

I'm using this script to upload a file to S3, which is part of https://github.com/tadruj/s3upload-coffee-javascript. Some function parameters have been changed slightly, but otherwise it is the same script. The upload itself works fine, however the progress does not update as the file is uploaded in Edge. When I upload the file, it stays at 0%, and then jumps to 100% once it is finished, with nothing in between. This is not a problem in Chrome or Firefox.

From what I can tell, the problem seems to be in the code

```
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
          var percentLoaded;
          if (e.lengthComputable) {
            percentLoaded = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
            return this_s3upload.onProgress(percentLoaded, (percentLoaded === 100 ? 'Finalizing.' : 'Uploading.'), public_url, file);
```

The event listener for for the file upload progress isn't firing, and the debugger seems to confirm this. What could be the issue here?

Comment: MDN says `XHMLHttpRequest.upload` should work on Edge 12. But maybe use `xhr.onprogress` instead of `xhr.upload.onprogress`?

Comment: Which version of Edge browser are you using (I have tested [this sample](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/progress_event), the progress works well on Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0 version)? how to display the rate of progress? Try to log process information in the on progress function, then, using F12 Console tools to check whether you could load the rate of progress, if it could log the rate of progress, the issue is related to the progress display part of the code.

Comment: @Barmar xhr.onprogress is only for downloading, not uploading

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I'm using 42.17143.1.0. Looking into whether the Edge version is a problem, I came across this https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12224510/. Looks like the functionality broke in certain versions of Edge

Comment: I was worried that might be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's just a problem with some versions of Edge, according to this https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12224510/. The issue was fixed in EdgeHTML version 18.17763.